# How can i do my <mat-card> doesn't expand when messages are displayed in Angular 9

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material, ng-bootstrap

I have my `<mat-card>` that has one form for the login of my page, the problem is when the error messages are displayed they change the size of the `<mat-card>` vertically and i need it to stay in the same size.

How can i do that?

- Below i will let my html file , the sass file of the error messages and pictures of what I have

***html file***

```html
<div class="bg"> 
    <div class="main-div color ">
        <mat-card class="z-depth center col-sm-4 " flex="50" >
            <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" [(ngModel)]="radio_btn">
                <mat-radio-button  [value]="true" >User</mat-radio-button>
                <mat-radio-button [value]="false">Admin</mat-radio-button>
            </mat-radio-group> 

                <div class="row justify-content-center " *ngIf="radio_btn==true;else form2">
                    <form class="example-form " [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="sendUser()">
                        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width ">
                            <input matInput formControlName="Identifier" placeholder="Identifier" >
                        </mat-form-field><br>
                        <div class=" alert-danger space" *ngIf="identifier.invalid && (identifier.dirty || identifier.touched)">
                            <div class="container-error-message " *ngIf="identifier.errors.required">
                                Identifier required
                            </div>
                            <div class="container-error-message" *ngIf="identifier.errors.minlength">
                                Identifier must be at least 7 characters long.
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                            <input matInput formControlName="Password" placeholder="Password" type="password" >
                        </mat-form-field><br>
                        <div class="alert-danger space" *ngIf="password.invalid && (password.dirty || password.touched)">
                            <div class="container-error-message" *ngIf="password.errors.required">
                                Password required
                            </div>
                            <div class="container-error-message" *ngIf="password.errors.minlength">
                                Password must be at least 5 characters long.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <button mat-raised-button [class.black]="!loginForm.invalid" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <ng-template #form2> 
                    <app-home-admin></app-home-admin>
                </ng-template>

        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </div>
```

***SASS file***

```css
@import './../../variables_scss/variables.scss';

example-icon {
    padding: 0 14px;
  }

  .example-spacer {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }

  .down{
    overflow-y: auto;
    .colour{
        //background: #141519;
        background: $orange-bg;
        .icons {
            color: $black;
          }
      }
  }

  .container{
    align-items: center; 
  }

  .main-div{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    .center{
      width: 75%;
      margin: 10px auto;
      .mat-radio-button ~ .mat-radio-button {
        margin-left: 16px;
      }
      button {
        display: block;            
        width: 100%;
        margin: 2px;
        text-align: center;
        color: $orange !important;
        border-radius: 8px;
      }

    }
  }

.bg{
  background: $black;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, $dark_black,$light_black  );
}
.behind{
  z-index: 10;
}
.black {
  background-color:$black !important;  
 }

 .space{
  margin: $margin-errors;
  text-align: $text-align-center;
  width: $width-erros;
  border: 1px solid;
 }
```

*** scss_variables***

```css
$dark_black: #1b1b1b;
$light_black: #424242;
$black: #141519;
$margin-left: auto;
$orange:  #fc6407;
$colour_button :$black;
$orange-bg: linear-gradient(to right, #c43e00, #ff6f00);
$margin-errors: 0 auto;
$text-align-center: center;
$width-erros: 180px;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz for your issue?

Comment: Sorry my project its to long to putt in in stackblitz, putting this part will give me errors

Comment: True but you can only replicate your issue in stackblitz by just adding the required code. Right now we cannot see the entire CSS or i cannot replicate your issue.

Comment: I updated the question with all the scss file, look at them and tell me if you can replicate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***This is how i solve it***

Adding this to the space class

```css
max-height: 0px ;
margin-top: 0px !important;
```

Adding this to the center class

```css
height: 290px;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to replicate your issue with the code given by you. But i would suggest you to provide a constant height to mat-card which is sufficient to enclose all the items. Like i am taking 400px below:

```
mat-card {
  height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Yes i tried with that but the `<mat-card>` is still growing, i don't know how to put it in a way he just stay in a same size always, if you need me to put more, code example the `ts` file I can because this is very urgent for me

Comment: can you please create stackblitz ? Just put this code in app component so that i can see your issue. We can also discuss this over chat if you need.

Comment: So can you please provide width to mat-card instead of main-div. I am waiting for your response over chat.

Comment: Sorry i was out can we discuss in the private chat?

Answer (score 0):

You can add maximum height and minimum hight of card as same like this in your CSS file , it's worked for me, if you done like this then if the content size is height,automatically scroll will be apply without any size correction

```
  .mat-card{
    min-height: 230px ;
    max-height: 230px ;
  }
```